# Trouble with jQuery to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I have simple menu script in jQuery. I want to refactor code to pure JavaScript. The purpose is maximize performance. But I have error "cannot read property 'addEventListener' or null". What am I doing wrong?

jQuery:

```
$('#menu li').on('touchstart click', function (e) {

e.preventDefault();

var item = $(this);
var submenu = item.find('ul');

// Display submenu, if there is one
// Otherwise follow the link
if (submenu.length > 0) {
    submenu.addClass('open');
    return;
} else {
    var link = item.find('a');
    window.location = link.attr('href');
}
```

});

JavaScript:

```
let menu = document.getElementById('#menu');
let menuItem = menu.getElementsByTagName('li');

menuItem.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

let submenu = this.find('ul');

// Display submenu, if there is one
// Otherwise follow the link
if (submenu.length > 0) {
    submenu.classList.add("open");
    return;
} else {
    let link = this.find('a');
    window.location.replace(href);
}
});
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the `#` when calling `getElementById`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to loop each item from the 'li' list since you are getting all 'li' available:

```
let menuItems = menu.getElementsByTagName('li');

for(let menuItem of menuItems) {
    ...
};
```